# Redirect a URL with two query string parameters to a new domain with a changed path using Apache's rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rules

I'm trying to do the following thing:

Transform URL: `https://example.com/human/?system=jitsi&action=SYSTEM`

to: `https://new.example/?action=SYSTEM&system=jitsi`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}   GET
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" action=(.+) 
RewriteRule / https://new.example/?action=SYSTEM&system=%1?
```

Unfortunately I can't get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules have several problems:

- You aren't matching the `human/` in the URL path that you are trying to remove.
- Neither your condition nor your rule has regex markers for "starts with" (`^`) or "ends with" (`$`) which means that they are matching substrings rather than full strings.
- Your rule starts with a slash which means that it can't be used in `.htaccess`, only in Apache's conf files.  I recommend starting rules with an optional slash `/?` so that they can be used in either context.
- Your query string condition is only matching one of the two parameters that you say need to be present to redirect.
- `(.+)` in your query string condition can match too much. It would include other parameters separated by an ampersand (`&`). This should be changed to `([^&]+)` meaning "at least one character not including ampersands"
- You have an extra stray `?` at the end of your target URL that would be interpreted as part of the value of the `system` parameter.
- You don't explicitly specify flags for redirect (`[R]`) or last (`[L]`) which are best practice to include.

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}   GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^system=([^&]+)&action=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?human/$ https://new.example/?action=%2&system=%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Esteban, Thanks for your answer. I have tested the transformation and it has been successful.
If you can provide me with useful information to have more knowledge I would be very grateful.
It was a very complex conversion and I couldn't find a way to carry it out.
Thanks again.